# Visual Studio 15 Preview 2 - Where is the Nuget Package Manager?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I just installed Visual Studio 15 Preview 2 (The newest one) and I have notice when right clicking on your solution there is no "Manage Nuget Packages" option (or what ever the old one was called) has the nuget thing been totally removed or not? can someone help me with this because Microsoft hasn't really helped me much with it and google hasn't given me much help either..

Comment: Do you have Extensions and Updates in the Tools menu?  If so, that dialog allows you to 'Search' in the upper right to find NuGet in the Online Library for installation.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to install the NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio 15 Preview extension.

Tools > Extensions and Updates > Online

Then search for NuGet and download the official NuGet Package Manager extension by Microsoft Corporation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Visual Studio 2017 RC. You have to rerun the installer (vs_installer.exe) then go to the "Individual Components" tab, scroll down to "Code tools" and add "Nuget package manager".

[image]